# converting to posixct fails

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

```
> resulttable[3,1]
     UTC FORECAST TIME
1: 2018-05-01 00:30:00
> as.POSIXct(resulttable[3,1],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
Error in as.POSIXct.default(resulttable[3, 1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",  :       
do not know how to convert 'resulttable[3, 1]' to class “POSIXct”
```

I don't understand the error, because the first column of resulttable is formatted as posixct

```
> lapply(resulttable,class)
$`UTC FORECAST TIME`
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$`UTC FORECAST RECEIVE TIME`
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Why does `as.POSIXct(resulttable[3,1],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")` lead to an error?

edit: Here the output of str:

```
> str(resulttable[3,1])
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ UTC FORECAST TIME: POSIXct, format: "2018-05-01 00:30:00"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems, its already in POSIXct, what is your goal here ?

Comment: What is the output of `str(resulttable[3,1])`? It seems to be a data.frame.

Comment: @PKumar yes correct. The as.posixct statement is used in another function and formats a non-posixct format to posixct. But if the incoming data is already posixct it gives this error. The thing is, i don't know before what kind of date format is incoming.

Comment: I'm assuming that `class(resulttable[[3, 1]]) == POSIXct`. Just use double square braces for type.

Comment: @RuiBarradas edited my initial post, it is a data.table

Comment: @KevinArseneau yes correct,  class(resulttable[[3, 1]])
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Comment: can you add an if statement to check the class of your input before attempting the conversion?

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(resulttable[3, 1][[1]], etc)`. The problem is that when you index like `[3, 1]` you generally have a vector, but in this case you have a `data.table` with two columns.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you, that worked. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the output of `str(resulttable[3,1])`. It says that it is an object of classes `data.table` and `data.frame`. Therefore, you must extract the column or columns you want to convert to `POSIXct` with the standard extraction operators.

```
resulttable[3, 1][[1]]                   # a vector
resulttable[3, 1]$`UTC FORECAST TIME`    # the same vector
```

Note that the column name, `UTC FORECAST TIME` has spaces in it so you need to put it between back quotes.
Then, in order to do the conversion you can use any of the above forms.

```
as.POSIXct(resulttable[3,1][[1]], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
as.POSIXct(resulttable[3,1]$`UTC FORECAST TIME`, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
```